# Unable to connect to cloud9 over LAN

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, lan, cloud9-ide

I've installed cloud 9 Ubuntu 14.04 (Desktop), and executed it by typing:

```
node [cloud9folder]/server.js -p 8080 -a :
```

I was able to connect to it by typing localhost:8080 (On the same computer that is running cloud 9) but when I went on another computer on the same network, I was unable to connect by typing [ip address of the computer running cloud9]:8080 into the browser. The browser returned: "Webpage not available (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)."

I know the server computer is working, I was able to access it's apache2 website but for some reason it is unable to connect to cloud 9.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

also add `-l 0.0.0.0` by default server is listening on `127.0.0.1` which is not public